# Android - Запланированная операция

Tags: java, android

Прошу подсказать в каком направлении двигаться! 
Есть запланированная задача, которая нормально выполняется. Но при входе приложения в onPause() задача перестает выполняться и находится в режиме ожидания, как и все приложение. Как заставить выполняться задачу на onPause(). AlarmManager не рассматриваю.

```
scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (flag) {                   
                sendSO2();
            } else {
                sendSO1();
            }
        }
    }, 10, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Чем вам AlarmManager не подходит?..

Comment: AlarmManager продолжает выполняться, когда приложение закончило свою работу, а это мне не нужно. Только из-за этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что вы имеете в виду... Если вы хотите чтоб задача выполнялась только когда приложение активно - просто в методе onResume() переопределить scheduledExecutorService. Елси чтоб выполнялась в любое другое время после запуска приложения, то можно воспользоваться Service(хотя это, вероятно, избыточно). Так же можно рассмотреть TimerTask, правда не знаю как он себя ведет после onPause().

Comment: а подскажите как переопределить scheduledExecutorService в методе onResume()?

Comment: Просто ещё раз выполнить ту конструкцию, которую вы написали. Т к выполнение события все равно, как вы говорите, стоит на паузе, то, поскольку на него не будет ссылки, сборщик мусора сам удалит объект Runnable. PS: "переопределить" - возможно я не совсем верно сказал, скорее "создать новый объект Runnable"

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!